# Terraform gathering of AWS OU structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations

Please help to understand, if I am able at all to collect all OUs using Terraform?

The case is that I'm using the next template :

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "this" {
}

data "aws_organizations_organizational_units" "ou" {
  parent_id = data.aws_organizations_organization.this.roots[0].id
}

locals {
  oulist = [for ou in data.aws_organizations_organizational_units.ou.children: ou.name => ou.id]
}
```

as result I have the list of OUs, but inside not included sub-ous which also present on my organization.
Is there any way to do gathering recursively?

Comment: The data source says the following: `Get all direct child organizational units under a parent organizational unit. This only provides immediate children, not all children.`. So maybe you can combine this with an AWS CLI command.

Comment: @ Alex Jamerton I'm having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?